# Hackerrank solution runs on PC, and Hackerrank but recieves Runtime Error when submitting

Tags: c#, .net

I have solved Day 8: Dictionaries and Maps on Hackerrank, code runs successfully but when ever I submit I keep getting a Runtime Error. The problem involves using a Dictionary/Map/HashMap data structure to build a phonebook. It is pass day 8, and I have been stuck here for too long.
Here is my solution:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Solution {
    static void Main (String[] args) {
        //read number of testcases
        int numOfTestCases = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

        //intantaite dictionary collection
        Dictionary<string, int> PhoneBook = new Dictionary<string, int> ();

        //Read key/value pairs on a single line

        for (int counter = 0; counter < numOfTestCases; counter++) {
            string[] tokens = Console.ReadLine ().Split (' ');
            string keys = tokens[0].ToLower ();
            int values = Convert.ToInt32 (tokens[1]);

            //Adding key/value pairs
            PhoneBook.Add (keys, values);
        }

        //Console.Write("Enter user name to search phonebook");
        for (var i = 0; i < numOfTestCases; i++) {
            string query = Console.ReadLine ().ToLower ();

            if (PhoneBook.ContainsKey (query) == true) {
                int output = PhoneBook[query];
                Console.WriteLine ("{0}={1}", query, output);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine ("Not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any more detail on the error itself? otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: please share the exact exception text

Comment: Sorry *Runtime Error** is the only error displayed by Hackerrank

Comment: A link to the task on HackerRank can be very helpful. And which test case produces this error? Or you have this error with every test case?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/problem
Test case 1 keeps failing

Comment: I mean, what the input in that test case? And you are trying exactly the same input on your local machine and your code is working well, right?